# ArcGIS plugin for Unity3d on Mac m1

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcgis, apple-m1

I've [downloaded the ArcGIS plugin](https://developers.arcgis.com/downloads/#unity) (.tgz) and, using Unity's plugin manager, imported the .tgz file. Instructions [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/unity/install-and-set-up/add-the-plugin-to-an-existing-project/)

However, I have errors in my console: [image]

Despite the errors, I get the ArcGIS Maps SDK menu item but clicking on "Map Creator" does not do anything...

Any idea what is going on? Does ArcGIS even work with Unity and/or Mac M1s?

Answer (score 0):

ESRI at this time doesn't support M1. So you can run tutorials with that plugin only with Unity Intel version. Hope in the future will provide also a plugin for Silicon versions of Unity!